# USB 3.0 ports on newly built PC don’t recognize USB 3.0 devices

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, usb-3

I have recently bought and built a new PC: Windows 8 Enterprise x64, and [Gigabyte GA-Z87-HD3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4489#ov) motherboard. Now, everything is put together and installed, I am facing only *one* problem.

I own an [Adata Nobility NH13](http://www.adata.com/?action=product_feature&cid=2&piid=132) external hard disk drive which is USB 3.0. When I plug it into any USB 3.0 port using a USB 3.0 cable, the drive does not show up in “My Computer,” nor in “Device Manager,” regardless of whether I use the Front or Rear USB 3.0 ports.

The USB 2.0 ports work just fine with it but what is the point in having a USB 3.0 device if you don’t use it the way you should?

If I plug USB 2.0 devices into the USB 3.0 ports, they work great, and if I connect the external hard disk drive with a USB 2.0 cable it does work.

Now, the first thing you would think is that the USB 3.0 drivers are missing, but in the Device Manager, under "USB Controllers", there is an entry for the "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller-0100 (Microsoft)".

If anyone has any suggestions, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other USB 3.0 devices you can try?

Comment: @Ramhound sadly no, but it works just fine everywhere else... When I plug it into the usb3 port on my laptop it works just fine..

Comment: I own an Adata Nobility NH13 for a while. It doesn't work on usb3 port.
I just tried Toshiba CANVIO ALU and it works perfectly.
Tried upgrading PCI driver and it says it's up to date. PC is IdeaCentre Lenovo.

Comment: I've had similar and it was a driver issue, or a driver conflict issue...

Comment: in bios look for `xhci handoff` it will be either disabled or enabled, try the alternative settings and reboot.  this is a suggestion, since i am not a win8 person and u already said usb3 drivers seems to be installed.